# Sublime Text 2 - set build system for specific project

Tags: ubuntu, sublimetext2, build-system

I would like to set a specific build system for a project. In that case I don't have to switch  the build system every time I switch a project. I tried to define the build system inside the project file following the instructions I found on this [website](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/projects.html).

I switched build system to automatic but sublime still uses the default c++ build system.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 32 Bit.

Comment: did this ever get resolved? I can't get this to work either.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `tools -> Build System` and select the one that you defined in your project file, otherwise Sublime will use it's automatic build system or the predefined one for C++.

If you don't see the name of your buildsystem, then you've probably defined it wrong and should post your `project json` here on SO.